What Exactly Is Symplecticity in the Context of Hamiltonian Systems and Numerical Schemes?
I've encountered the term symplecticity in the study of Hamiltonian systems and their numerical discretizations, but I'm struggling to fully grasp its meaning and significance. Initially, I thought symplecticity was just a weaker form of the conservation of the Hamiltonian, but I've since learned that this isn't entirely accurate.
From my current understanding, in the context of numerical schemes for differential equations, symplectic integrators don't necessarily preserve the Hamiltonian exactly but instead do so up to an error of order $O(\Delta t^p)$ where $p$ is the order of the discretization method. This suggests symplecticity might be a structural property of the numerical method rather than a direct guarantee of Hamiltonian conservation.
Can someone clarify:

What exactly does symplecticity mean in the mathematical sense?
How does it relate to the geometry of Hamiltonian systems?
Why is it important for numerical schemes to preserve symplecticity, even if the Hamiltonian isn't preserved exactly?

I would greatly appreciate an explanation or pointers to resources that demystify this concept!

Did you encounter symplectic matrices or better symplectic bilinear forms (similar to symmetric matrices and scalar products)? Did you find it explained that the vector field in a Hamiltonian system is the symplectic gradient of the Hamiltonian?
